# showing git branch name in command prompt

Tags: git, zsh, prompt

Just curious if the following two always output the same thing (branch name)? I'm using zsh.

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null
```

versus

```
ref=$($git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null)
echo "${ref#refs/heads/}"
```

If not, is one way preferred over the other for setting up git context in command prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They behave the same when on a branch, but not when in "detached HEAD" mode (try `git checkout --detach master` for instance, followed by `git checkout master` to re-attach your head).

The real question to answer is: what do you want displayed in detached HEAD mode?  If you want an abbreviated hash, use the `rev-parse` format.  If you want something else, use the `symbolic-ref` format, perhaps with an additional clause to show "detached" or whatever, if `symbolic-ref` errors out.

Answer (score 1):

[@torec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) posted an excellent explanation of the differences between the 2, i just want to take it a bit further and to explain a bit more about the syntx of each command.

---

***`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null`***

---

## `rev-parse`

> ***`--abbrev-ref[=(strict|loose)]`***
> A non-ambiguous short name of the objects name.
> The option `core.warnAmbiguousRefs` is used to select the strict abbreviation mode.

## `HEAD`

[Read here all about HEAD (+detached `HEAD`) here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716)

So what this command does it simply get the SHA-1 of `HEAD` (`rev-parse`), and them converts it tote branch name (`--abbrev-ref`)

---

***`git symbolic-ref HEAD`***

> ***`symbolic-ref`***
> Given one argument, reads which branch head the given symbolic ref refers to and outputs its path, relative to the `.git/` directory.
>
> Typically you would give `HEAD` as the  argument to see **which branch your working tree is on**

The ( symbolic-ref ) is usually used if you wish to do something regrading refs (or refspec(